# Access - appending from two sources using unique multi-field ID. 1 field in 1 source formatted differently with leading 0s or letter

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am making updates to a database and am stuck with this problem. Appending to a destination with a unique two-field ID of, for example, `field1` and `field2`.

One source table, a ODBC linked table, has `field1` text with field size of 8. Second source table is linked xlsx file and is imported with `field1` as text with field size of 255.

`field1` values in both sources contain the same string, but in the xlsx linked table some values have leading zeros(one or two of them) or a leading W. I am trying to remove the leading characters so the field from both sources match up for the unique ID.

I have been researching how to trim leading zeros or characters, but with the combination of working from a linked xlsx table and trimming both numbers and letters I keep getting stuck. Since I run these queries each month I'm thinking it is most simple to create another table for modified strings to add and delete from that I can use to append to the destination table.

I found `CLng` function works on leading 0s but not leading Ws, those return `#Error` in the field. I was trying to create minimal new objects. Will I need to build two queries to trim leading characters, one for 0s and one for Ws?

**EDIT** I tried nesting a replace function within the conversion function but it is prompting for Enter Parameter Value for "W". I missed something. See code below:

```
SELECT Bag.field2, Bag.field1, CLng(Replace(([Bag]![field1]),“W”,“”)) AS [Edited Number], 
Bag.[Print Year], Bag.[Book Type], Bag.[Returned Date], Bag.[Return Checked In Status], 
Bag.Status, Bag.[SV Book], Bag.Destroyed, Bag.[Last Updated Date]
FROM Bag;
```

Sample data and desired output as follows:

| Starting Table | Ending Table |
| --- | --- |
| 00123456 | 123456 |
| 09876543 | 9876543 |
| W3456789 | 3456789 |

Comment: Some sample data and the desired output would be nice ...

Comment: Hi Gustav I made edits to add sample data and code. Data is formatted as a table in the edit screen but appears as text here. Sorry, I am unfamiliar with the table formatting here.

Comment: Your SQL includes type-setting quotes: `“W”,“”`  Not sure whether those are actually present in your real code, but make sure you have plain quotes instead: `"W",""` Or in Access SQL you can use single quotes: `'W',''`

Comment: What happens if you try this? `CLng(Replace(Bag.field1, 'W', ''))`

Comment: Thanks HansUp, I think that was it. I was making some edits in word and when I pasted back into SQL it must have carried those funny quotes. I replaced them in Access with double quotes it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can nest string manipulation and conversion functions. Consider:

```
CLng(Replace(field, "W", ""))
```

Comment: hi June thanks again for your input. I ran into a "enter parameter value" prompt for "w" but replace and nested functions are still new to me so I assume I misplaced a character somewhere. I made edits above to include code.

Comment: Nvm, I found it was due to type-setting quotes. Probably due to copy/pasting from Word where I was making the edits? Anyway, after replacing the quotes in Access it ran fine. Desired output has been achieved. Thanks again